# How do I find an `f` that makes `pcall(pcall, f)` return `false` in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm using Lua 5.3.

Reading 'Programming in Lua 3rd edition', I came into an exercise asking me to find an `f` that makes `pcall(pcall, f)` return `false`. I think this is equivalent to make `pcall(f)` raise an error. But seems use `pcall` on anything won't do that. For example, let `f = nil` and nothing bad happens.

However, I found on the internet that letting `f = (function() end)()` does the trick. But I don't understand why. Here `f` is just the return value (which is `nil`) of the function `function() end` right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not work

```
> f = (function() end)()
> pcall(pcall, f)
true    false   attempt to call a nil value
```

but this does:

```
> pcall(pcall,(function() end)())
false   bad argument #1 to 'pcall' (value expected)
```

The difference is that `(function() end)()` returns no value, which is different from returning `nil`.
Functions written in Lua cannot make this distinction but `pcall` is written in C and can make this distinction. (Other examples are `print` and `type`.)

Note that this behaves as expected (equivalent to the first attempt):

```
> pcall(pcall,(function() return nil end)())
true    false   attempt to call a nil value
```

Comment: Thanks. So it's something not worth noticing?

Comment: "Functions written in Lua cannot make this distinction": this is something that `select('#',...)` can provide, isn't it: `(function(...) print(select('#', ...)) end)((function() end)())`?

Comment: @PaulKulchenko, yes, but you need help from a library function such as `select`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the code you are calling is equivalent to `pcall(pcall)`, not to `pcall(pcall, nil)`. The function doesn't return anything; it's *adjusted* to `nil` in some contexts, but is still different from `nil` in other contexts (as is the case in this example).